# Internet Connection in Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v

Please help me with this.

- I want to run my windows phone 8 emulator by enabling Internet connection in both the host machine and the emulator.
- When i searched for enabling Internet connection, i have understood that, it needs two dedicated NIC's. One for the host machine and the other one for emulator.
- SO, i thought by enabling the Ethernet and wifi connections on my laptop, it will get two separate network adapters, so that i can use one of them for the host machine and the other one for the emulator.
- But i dont know how to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am also having this type of problem and finally i got success.

1.go to control panel and **disable Hyper-v** just only unchecked all Hyper-V options.

1. run VMware set up you can download from here.
   [downloadworkstation](http://www.vmware.com/go/downloadworkstation)
2. again go to control panel and **enable Hyper-V**.

4.you run the emulator you have a dialog box click Retry and click Yes

5.**run VS** and enjoy with internet on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx

Cannot connect to Internet destinations

---

The Windows Phone 8 Emulator uses the HTTP proxy settings from the host computer. If you can’t access Internet resources from the emulator, check with your IT administrator to make sure that your proxy settings will work with the emulator.

If your network’s proxy servers are unavailable or malfunctioning, it might be possible to restore connectivity for the emulator by disabling automatic proxy detection on the host computer. However this only works in certain network configurations.

To disable automatic proxy detection on the host computer

1.
On the host computer, open Internet Options from the Control Panel. The Internet Properties dialog box opens.

2.
In the Internet Properties dialog box, click the Connections tab.

3.
On the Connections page, click the LAN settings button. The Local Area Network (LAN) Settings dialog box opens.

4.
In the Local Area Network (LAN) Settings dialog box, deselect all the check boxes. Click OK twice to close both dialog boxes.

5.
Restart the emulator and retry the connection.